# Calculate the force needed to move a ball on a horizontal plane?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, friction, rotation

Lets say I have a stationary ball on a horizontal plane. I want to find how much horizontal force is needed to push the ball so it starts moving. The only forces that would be acting on this ball would be friction force and whatever horizontal pushing force is applied. The ball has mass $M$, radius $R$ and the coefficient of friction $\mu$. I know how to calculate the pulling force for a block but i interested in finding the force needed for a ball which is much different where the moment of inertia places a much bigger role. I am assuming rolling without slipping and no air resistance.

This is not a homework problem! I am designing a spring mechanism that would push a ball on the ground and need calculate the minimum force needed to move the ball.

Comment: For a real object, it depends on the rolling resistance, which is not related to the coefficient of friction.  For an ideal object, any nonzero force results in a nonzero acceleration.

Comment: @BowlOfRed is there away i can include an expression for rolling resistance in the equation? if yes, what would it be? it doesn't need to be perfect but need something that would give realistic results.

Comment: Equations for it normally are for load at steady-state rolling (such as on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance).  Your question about force needed to begin is slightly different and isn't captured in the equations.  It's probably very non-linear and would be easier to measure than calculate.

Comment: Why don't you do an experiment and *measure* the force? Why do you have to *calculate* it?

Comment: @sammygerbil   the ball i am using is relatively small (20mm diameter) so measuring the force accurately would be really difficult in my opinion. So all the suggestions already given would be very hard to implement. With that being said, I am open to any suggestions on how to measure the force needed.

Comment: Once you have the value of the force, whether by calculation or measurement, how will that solve your design problem? Will it tell you which spring to buy, or how much to compress it? Wouldn't it be easier (and more direct) to test a couple of springs as you intend to use them?

Comment: @sammygerbil i need to know which spring to buy. It needs to be done prior to getting the spring because the application i need it for it will need to be custom built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can estimate the force required to get the ball rolling by tilting the plane until the ball just begins to move.

The force pushing the ball down the plane is then $mgy/L$ where $L$ is the length of the plane and $y$ is height off the ground at the lifted end.

Comment: thank you I appreciate the creativity and the simplicity of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the rolling equivalent of Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum\tau=I\alpha$$

$I$ is moment of inertia and $\alpha$ the rotational acceleration. You want to find the situation where $\alpha$ becomes non zero, which happens when all torques $\tau$ don't cancel out. Ideally there will be *no* resistance to rolling (nothing is sliding experiencing kinetic friction so nothing is slowed down), so the tiniest torque you can exert will be the only torque present and the ball will roll.

As @BowlofRed mentions, in the real world there will always be some *rolling* resistance because of tiny deformations of ball and surface. You will need to estimate that, which can vary very much depending on surface.

When you have an estimated rolling friction force, you can calculate it's torque: $\tau_r=F_r R$ ($R$ is ball radius). This is what your applied torque must overcome with a counter torque. You can increase the torque, by exerting your force further from the center, as the formula shows.